# Data type not found error in JDBC connection in java?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

I am using Microsoft Access database for storing data. In that, I stored date as "DATE/TIME" data type. While getting date from the following code it produces error..

```
        String sql    =   "Select prev_date from StaffAdvance where Staff_ID='"+date+"'";
        ResultSet rs  =   st.executeQuery(sql);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Staff_ID is a date? (btw, posting the full stacktrace is always a good idea).

Comment: what is the type of a date object. is it java.util.Date or java.sql.Date

Comment: Staff_ID has no proper business being a date...

Think what you're doing...

Comment: Yes Mr. Martin Milan.. I used no proper name, but used correct way in application..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told the type of date object is java.util.Date, change the type to java.sql.Date and try.

Comment: Yes i got it.. My friend told should use "#" instead of "'" in that query.. That is
String sql    =   "Select prev_date from StaffAdvance where Staff_ID=#"+date+"#";
        ResultSet rs  =   st.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: did you change the type of date to sql.Date

Comment: The hash marks work because this is the date delimiter for Jet/ACE SQL.